# MYSQL query syntax correction

Tags: mysql

Need some help on MYSQL query syntax, I am able to get last 60 records but wanted to exclude this week's record. I am trying following but can't able to figure out correct syntax.

```
select TIMESTAMP,ID,MAX,MIN from 
 (select TIMESTAMP,ID,MAX,MIN from db 
  where ID = 'A0101'  
  WHERE YEARweek(TIMESTAMP) =! YEARweek(current_DATE) 
  group by TIMESTAMP desc limit 60) t 
order by TIMESTAMP asc
```

Comment: Is this your query? Two `where` clause in one select? No error?

Answer (score 2):

```
select TIMESTAMP,ID,MAX,MIN from db 
  where ID = 'A0101'  
  AND YEARweek(TIMESTAMP) != YEARweek(current_DATE) 
  group by TIMESTAMP desc limit 60
order by TIMESTAMP asc
```

more like this...

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is just the `=!` which negates `YEARweek()` and compares to the other `YEARweek()`.

You should try `!=` instead.

Currently, I cannot tell more, as you don't show what is wrong or what happens or doesn't happen with your query.

Comment: right. Needs two, three more glances on it - would have been easier to spot if original would be accompagnied by an error message. ("It doesn't work" is none.)